# How to export a typescript Google Cloud Function from separate file?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

### **Structure**

```
functions
|--src
    |--index.ts
    |--Admin
        |--querys.ts
        |--migrations.ts
```

### **Objective**

I have written a Google Cloud function which uses the Admin SDK to query my Firestore database. This function is written in the `querys.ts` file but needs to be exported from `index.ts`
Here's what I have now:

```
index.ts

import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { query } from './Admin/querys';
export const readData = functions
  .https(query);
```

```
querys.ts

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const db = admin.firestore();

export async function query() {
  const dataRef = db.collection('Collection')
  const res = await dataRef.get()
  if (res.size == 0) {
    return console.log("The query is empty")
  } else {
    res.forEach(doc => {
      const data = doc.data().consolidatedBucketId
      fs.writeFile('QueryOutput.txt', `${data} \n`, { flag: "a+" }, (err) => {
        console.log('There was an error writing to the file: ', err);
      })
      return res
    })
  }
}
```

The call to `.https(query)` is throwing an error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type '{ onRequest: (handler: (req: Request, resp: Response<any>) => void | Promise<void>) => HttpsFunction; onCall: (handler: (data: any, context: CallableContext) => any) => TriggerAnnotated & ... 1 more ... & Runnable<...>; }' has no call signatures.
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial: [Can I write my Cloud Functions in separate file?](https://jsmobiledev.com/article/functions-multiple-files) however, the example they used was not an `https` invoked and I am having trouble writing the solution I need.

**Assumption:**

It seems I am not returning the promise from the `async` function properly?

Comment: I'd suggest first writing it all in the same file, make sure that works, then break out the parts you want in another file.  As it stands now, your function seems to be missing a lot of code in general.  I'm not even sure what it's supposed to do.  You'll be more likely to get help if you show a working function next to your non-working function to see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the whole function in the separate file seems to do the trick:

**index.ts:**

```
import {queryFunc} from './Admin/querys'

export const query = queryFunc
```

**query.ts:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export const queryFunc = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const dataRef = db.collection('Collection')
  const dataSnapshot = await dataRef.get()
  if (dataSnapshot.size == 0) {
    return console.log("The query is empty")
  } else {
    dataSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const data = doc.data().consolidatedBucketId
      fs.writeFile('QueryOutput.txt', `${data} \n`, { flag: "a+" }, (err) => {
        console.log('There was an error writing to the file: ', err);
      })
    })
    return res.send(dataSnapshot)
    // ^ Send the response back
  }
});

// I've renamed res (from Firestore) to dataSnapshot to avoid confusion
```

Comment: There are no errors thrown by tslint. However, when I try to deploy the function I receive this: `Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2`

Comment: @Garrett Could you test running the functions on local emulator? Also the `res.send()` should be out of forEach loop. Please share a complete screenshot of the error.

Comment: screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ihJdUPk. I looked at the wrong error, not used to seeing other files on deploy, apologies. After moving the return outside of the loop and trying the attached link there are other issues. This question is starting to lose focus. Your help has been great but its becoming inappropriate for a stack overflow thread maybe. I might take doug's advice and create a more focused question tomorrow/later. garrettohara2018@gmail if you would like to chat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300271/firebase-admin-sdk-error-expression-has-type-void-put-it-on-its-own-line-as

Comment: @Garrett they seem to be ES Lint errors... but if it worked on emulator and you can use functions from other files, you can accept the answer when confirmed. You can @ me when you have a MVP as mentioned by Doug later